# why i am not getting the correct outputs

Tags: c, math

ok so for my problem a magical number is defined as the following: if its every digit is larger than the sum of the digits which are on the right side of that digit.
for example 94210 9 is > 4+2+1+0 4 is >2+1+0 etc ...
i cant see the issue with my code but I don't get the correct output

```
    #include <stdio.h>
void Magic_number(int left, int right, int digit) {

    int remainder;
    for (; left < right; left++) {
        int flag = 1; int sum = 0; int y = left;
        remainder = y % 10; y = y / 10;
        sum += remainder;
        while (y != 0 && flag)
        {
            if (remainder == digit)
                flag = 0;
            if (remainder < sum)
                flag = 0;
            y = y / 10;
            remainder = y % 10;
            sum += remainder;
        }
        if (y == 0 && flag) {
            printf("%d ", left);
        }

    }
    }
    int main() {
    int l, r, d;
    printf("please enter the right bound \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &r);

    printf("please enter the left bound \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &l);
    while (l>r)
    {
        printf("please enter the left bound that is less than the right bound \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &l);
    }
    printf("please enter the arbitrary digit\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &d);
    printf("the Magic numbers from left bound%d  and the right bound %d while exluding %d\n", l, r, d);
    Magic_number(l, r, d);
}
```

```
expected output
magic number in rande left=740 right 850 with excluding digit m=2
740 741 750 751 760 810 830 831 840 841 843 850

the output I get 
740 750 760 770 780 790 800 810 820 830 840
```

Comment: Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result. Also, what debugging have you done? Use a debugger to step thru your code, examining the flow and state as it runs.

Comment: @kaylum i added the outputs

Comment: The actual output doesn't include 850 because the loop condition is `left < right`. If the upper bound is included in the range, the loop condition should be `left <= right`.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for that put that isnt the issue, the real issue is that I need to find the numbers from a certain range and exclude numbers with a number that the user inputs

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of bugs in your code. One example is inside the loop where you do  `y = y / 10;` before calculating the remainder. Since you already divide by 10 before the loop, you actually skip a digit. Further there are some places where you do `<` instead of `<=`

Try like:

```
void Magic_number(int left, int right, int digit) 
{
    int remainder;
    for (; left <= right; left++) {
        int flag = 1; int sum = 0; int y = left;
        
        remainder = y % 10;      // Get first digit
        y = y / 10;              // Update y
        sum += remainder;        // Update sum
        if (remainder == digit)  // Check if first digit must be skipped
            flag = 0;
            
        while (y != 0 && flag)
        {
            remainder = y % 10;     // Get next digit
            y = y / 10;             // Update y
            if (remainder == digit) // Check if current digit must be skipped
                flag = 0;
            if (remainder <= sum)   // Check if current digit is higher than current sum
                flag = 0;
            sum += remainder;       // Update sum
        }
        if (y == 0 && flag) {
            printf("%d ", left);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much man now i see where my mistakes at